# Hibernate - Generate entity from MySql thow MalformedByteSequenceException

Tags: mysql, encoding, hibernate-mapping, reverse

i'm dealing with hibernate project with spring and without make changes in the configuration of hibernate (svn say so) i'va added one column to the DB (tinyint(1) because i needed a bolean value) and from then i get this exception

[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Hr6Nv9fC)

```
!ENTRY org.hibernate.eclipse 4 666 2017-10-25 16:56:21.976
!MESSAGE java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Byte non valido 1 della sequenza UTF-8 a 1 byte.
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Byte non valido 1 della sequenza UTF-8 a 1 byte.
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.XMLPrettyPrinter.prettyFormat(XMLPrettyPrinter.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.XMLPrettyPrinter.prettyPrintFile(XMLPrettyPrinter.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.ArtifactCollector.formatXml(ArtifactCollector.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.ArtifactCollector.formatFiles(ArtifactCollector.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.start(AbstractExporter.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractExporterFacade.start(AbstractExporterFacade.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension$1.execute(ConsoleExtension.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension.runExporters(ConsoleExtension.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension.launchExporters(ConsoleExtension.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.CodeGenerationLaunchDelegate.launch(CodeGenerationLaunchDelegate.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Byte non valido 1 della sequenza UTF-8 a 1 byte.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:701)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:567)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1895)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1761)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1799)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanTextDecl(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:767)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDExternalSubset(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.xml.AbstractXMLPrettyPrinterStrategy.newDocument(AbstractXMLPrettyPrinterStrategy.java:23)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.xml.TrAXPrettyPrinterStrategy.prettyPrint(TrAXPrettyPrinterStrategy.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.XMLPrettyPrinter.prettyFormat(XMLPrettyPrinter.java:38)
    ... 21 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.hibernate.eclipse 4 666 2017-10-25 16:56:21.977
!MESSAGE java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Byte non valido 1 della sequenza UTF-8 a 1 byte.
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Byte non valido 1 della sequenza UTF-8 a 1 byte.
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.XMLPrettyPrinter.prettyFormat(XMLPrettyPrinter.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.XMLPrettyPrinter.prettyPrintFile(XMLPrettyPrinter.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.ArtifactCollector.formatXml(ArtifactCollector.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.ArtifactCollector.formatFiles(ArtifactCollector.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.start(AbstractExporter.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractExporterFacade.start(AbstractExporterFacade.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension$1.execute(ConsoleExtension.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension.runExporters(ConsoleExtension.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension.launchExporters(ConsoleExtension.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.CodeGenerationLaunchDelegate.launch(CodeGenerationLaunchDelegate.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Byte non valido 1 della sequenza UTF-8 a 1 byte.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:701)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:567)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1895)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1761)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1799)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanTextDecl(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:767)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDExternalSubset(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.xml.AbstractXMLPrettyPrinterStrategy.newDocument(AbstractXMLPrettyPrinterStrategy.java:23)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.xml.TrAXPrettyPrinterStrategy.prettyPrint(TrAXPrettyPrinterStrategy.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.XMLPrettyPrinter.prettyFormat(XMLPrettyPrinter.java:38)
    ... 21 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.hibernate.eclipse 4 666 2017-10-25 16:56:21.978
!MESSAGE com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Byte non valido 1 della sequenza UTF-8 a 1 byte.
!STACK 0
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Byte non valido 1 della sequenza UTF-8 a 1 byte.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:701)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:567)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1895)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1761)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1799)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanTextDecl(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:767)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDExternalSubset(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.xml.AbstractXMLPrettyPrinterStrategy.newDocument(AbstractXMLPrettyPrinterStrategy.java:23)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.xml.TrAXPrettyPrinterStrategy.prettyPrint(TrAXPrettyPrinterStrategy.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.XMLPrettyPrinter.prettyFormat(XMLPrettyPrinter.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.XMLPrettyPrinter.prettyPrintFile(XMLPrettyPrinter.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.ArtifactCollector.formatXml(ArtifactCollector.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.ArtifactCollector.formatFiles(ArtifactCollector.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.start(AbstractExporter.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractExporterFacade.start(AbstractExporterFacade.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension$1.execute(ConsoleExtension.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension.runExporters(ConsoleExtension.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.ConsoleExtension.launchExporters(ConsoleExtension.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.CodeGenerationLaunchDelegate.launch(CodeGenerationLaunchDelegate.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

i've tried to rollback the db when i try to generate the entities again i'll get the same error.

The error seems to appen when the process start to generate hbm.xml files, so for now, i remove from the hibernate configuration the generation of those files and everything works well.

Any idea on how i can get rid of this exception?

Thanks

Comment: it's done! thanks to a friend i've an answer at my own question :)

in this question i forgot to tell the most important detail, the editor i'm using: i'm using eclipse and for some reason i changed the encoding of the file, the encoding it's not a part of svn compare, but thanks to a friend of mine i've tried to change the encoding of my eclipse installation and everythigs now works well!! maybe this could help someone else

Comment: Smells like latin1 instead of utf8 somewhere.  Can you get the HEX of the 'bad' sequence?  And what it should be?